# How can ice cubes contain gas bubbles?

Tags: ice

It seems impossible for an ice cube to contain bubbles.  the ice should freeze far too slowly for a bubble to get trapped within it.  However, virtually all ice (that I have seen in my freezer) contains gas bubbles.  How is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are bubbles in ice at a lower or higher pressure than atmospheric pressure?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70994/)

Comment: Ironically in this case it's the question that explains how the bubbles form rather than the answers. It happens when dissolved gas is forced out of solution by freezing. So you don't have to trap the bubbles - they don't form until frezing stars and by then there is ice to hold them in place.

Comment: The solubility of N2 in liquid water is easily found (e.g. R. Battino, J. PHys. Chem. Ref. data Vol. 13(2), 563 (1984)). In brief, solubility increases with decreasing temperature. However, the solubility of N2 in ice is surprisingly hard to find - I don't have a good reference.  Given the observation of gas bubbles, I will assume for now that the solubility is lower in ice than the liquid and agree with @JohnRennie that it is simple thermodynamics driving the phase separation.